# How to set a breakpoint in threaded Python?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'm trying to set a breakpoint and it complains with 
`ValueError: Fatal exception in the data production loop: signal only works in main thread`

It is from `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/recommendation/data_pipeline.py`

```
class BaseDataConstructor(threading.Thread):

  ...

class BisectionDataConstructor(BaseDataConstructor):

  def construct_lookup_variables(self):

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

   def lookup_negative_items(self, negative_users, **kwargs):

     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
     output = np.zeros(shape=negative_users.shape, dtype=rconst.ITEM_DTYPE) - 1
```

https://bugs.python.org/issue13120 seems to suggest it's been fixed?
(it lists Versions: Python 3.2, Python 3.3, Python 3.4 , so I tried 3.4 and it works with 3.4) ...

I also tried code from
[pdb cannot break in another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828956/pdb-cannot-break-in-another-thread) and it gives me error as well

I'm on python 3.7.2 on ubuntu